# Using modulus to find difference between 2 times?

Tags: c++, time

I need to write a program that will tell me the difference between 2 times, in the 24 hour format.

So if I enter 22:30, it has to know that 22 = hours and 30 = minutes.

Also if I enter another time (23:50 for example) it needs to tell me that the difference is 1 hour and 20 minutes.

I’ve been playing around with it but I don’t really understand how modulus works.

I tried writing :

Arrival time = hours/100

hours % 100 but I know that doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: i guess using `%` was a hint, but you seem to be confused about how to apply the hint. Hence I suggest to step back and consider how you would transform the time to minutes only then get the difference and then... you can use the hint

Comment: anyhow, please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: *I don’t really understand how modulus works* Using a 12-hour clock, if it's 9 o'clock, and you add 7 hours, the clock says 4 o'clock.  (9 + 7) mod 12 = 4.

Comment: Which part is part of the homework? Is it making the program or understanding the remainder operator `%`? Both?

Comment: Are both times always on the same day? Or is it the case where if the second time is earlier than the first then it is understood to apply on the following day?

Comment: In addition to @Eljay's comment: The modulus is the remainder after integer division. E.g. 17 / 5 = 3 remainder 2. Now if you write in your program `int q = 17 / 5;` you'll end up with `q = 3`. If you use the `%`-operator instead, like in `int r = 17 % 5;`, you'll end up with `r = 2`.

Comment: I just need to understand how modulus works. It’s not homework for now.

Comment: It’s always on the same day.

Comment: In that case, compute the difference between the two times in minutes. (Do that by first converting each time to the number of minutes elapsed since midnight.) Call that m say. Take the absolute value of that number. Then m / 60 is the hours, and m % 60 is the minutes.

Answer (score 2):

> I just need to understand how modulus works.

Ok then lets consider you already have start and stop time as hour and minutes (both at the same day):

```
int start_h = 22;
int start_m = 30;
int stop_h = 23;
int stop_m = 50;
```

For easier caclulation of the difference we transform both to minutes:

```
start_m += start_h * 60;                  // 30 + (22*60) = 1350
stop_m += stop_h * 60;                    // 50 + (23*60) = 1430
int diff_m = std::abs(stop_m - start_m);  // 1430 - 1350 = 80
```

So far so good, the difference is `100` minutes. To split that again in hours and minutes you can use the `%` operator:

```
 int diff_h = diff_m / 60;      // 80 / 60 = 1 (integer arithmetics)
 diff_m = diff_m % 60;          // 80 % 60 = 20
```

The last line is equivalent to

```
 diff_m = diff_m - (diff_m / 60) * 60;  // again: integer arithmetics
```

Because `a % b` is the remainder from dividing `a` by `b`. `60` fits into `80` once to make a full hour, and then there are `20` minutes left over.

Comment: Suggest you use `std::abs(diff_m)` as funky things will happen if `diff_m` is negative.

Comment: Thanks for that. However I need that to happen no matter what time is entered, not just the example I gave.

Comment: @Username77373 hm? Then why in a comment you said "I just need to understand how modulus works." ? Anyhow, this does work for any values not only the one example

Comment: Well that’s one of the questions that i’m doing from a sheet I found.
You need to enter any time and it has to know what’s hours, what’s minutes and calculate the difference between 2 times.

Comment: @Username77373 and this answer explains how to get the difference by using `%`. Sorry, I dont understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 2):

not using modulus, but you can also use the `<chrono>` library to find difference between 2 times

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    //using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    
    //auto d = hh_mm_ss{(23h+50min)-(22h+30min)};
    auto d = hh_mm_ss{ (hours{23}+minutes{50}) - (hours{22}+minutes{30}) };

    std::cout << (d.is_negative() ? "negative " : "")
        << d.hours().count() << " hours "
        << d.minutes().count() << " minutes";
}
```

*note: [`std::chrono::hh_mm_ss`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss) require `c++20` (possible implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss/accessors))*